# my php code runs, loads, but no outputs

Tags: php, debugging, output, modular-design

I was trying to create a program in which simply generates license keys. Here it is:

```
<?php

function gen_code_alpha()
{
    $alpha = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        $alpha .= $i;
    }

    // This attaches alphabets from 'a' to 'z' to our $alpha
    for ($i = 65; $i <= 122; $i++) {
        $alpha .= chr($i);
    }
}

function gen_code($len = 1)
{
    gen_code_alpha();
    global $alpha;

    $strlen = strlen($alpha);

    $code = '';
    for ($k = 0; $k < $len; $k++) {
        $i = $rand(0, $strlen -1);// now wanna randomly generate the code
        $code .= substr($alpha, $i, 1);
    }

    return $code;
}

function gen_license_key()
{
    $licenseKey = gen_code(4) . '-' .
                  gen_code(4) . '-' .
                  gen_code(4) . '-' .
                  gen_code(4) . '-' .
                  gen_code(2);
}

gen_license_key();
echo $licenseKey;
```

But when I try to run it, it doesn't show any outputs. I'm new to PHP and I don't know alot about debugging, But I had some tries. I put some echos in the code which I understood my $alpha is being successfully generated in gen_code_alpha() function. I also tried to echo $licenseKey in gen_license_key() function which didn't help. I didn't find out anything more.

So what do you think?

Comment: Is `$licenseKey` a global variable?

Comment: `$licenseKey` is not [scoped](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) properly.

Comment: `gen_license_key()` does not return anything.

Comment: I also tried to echo $licenseKey in gen_license_key() function which didn't help.

Comment: gen_license_key(); isn't in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete code working

Notice that you have a typo (rand, not $rand)

I also would suggest that you change the code to avoid using global  variables, which is a bad practice.

```
<?php

function gen_code_alpha()
{
    global $alpha;

    $alpha = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        $alpha .= $i;
    }

    // This attaches alphabets from 'a' to 'z' to our $alpha
    for ($i = 65; $i <= 122; $i++) {
        $alpha .= chr($i);
    }
}

function gen_code($len = 1)
{
    gen_code_alpha();
    global $alpha;

    $strlen = strlen($alpha);

    $code = '';
    for ($k = 0; $k < $len; $k++) {
        $i = rand(0, $strlen -1);// now wanna randomly generate the code
        $code .= substr($alpha, $i, 1);
    }

    return $code;
}

function gen_license_key()
{
    $licenseKey = gen_code(4) . '-' .
                gen_code(4) . '-' .
                gen_code(4) . '-' .
                gen_code(4) . '-' .
                gen_code(2);
    return $licenseKey;
}

$licenseKey = gen_license_key();
echo "l:".$licenseKey;

?>
```

outputs:

```
 l:3X6D-gnQL-I0zJ-TRQD-Sq
```

Comment: `global $alpha` is defined twice

Comment: @justadev Thank you. I had wrongly add $ to the first of rand function.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, just change this:

```
function gen_license_key()
{
    // return the result instead of assigning it to a local variable
    return gen_code(4) . '-' .
           gen_code(4) . '-' .
           gen_code(4) . '-' .
           gen_code(4) . '-' .
           gen_code(2);
}
```

And then you can:

```
// show the key, do nothing else
echo gen_license_key();

// OR

// store the key in $licenseKey so you can do other stuff with it if needed
$licenseKey = gen_license_key();

// Now show the key
echo $licenseKey;
```

---

Additionally, set `global $alpha = '';` inside your `gen_code_alpha()` function or I highly recommend following a "return" pattern for programming functions.

Comment: Wouldn't `gen_license_key` still need a return value in your second solution?

Comment: This solution is great, because you want to try to avoid polluting the [global namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php).

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski sorry for the confusion. Changing the function to use `return` is required for both output methods. See my update.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that makes more sense, but his `gen_code_alpha()` function doesn't have a return value so this still won't work. EDIT: never mind, I just noticed the `global` keyword

Comment: @Amirali Use my answer as a guide to fix your other functions. Avoid global variables at all costs because they are a cancer to PHP. This isn't code review; if you made the mistake once then verify the rest of your code isn't causing the same issue. I'm not your mother.

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski See my update again. Globals should be avoided at all cost in modern PHP...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I returned $alpha in gen_code_alpha() and $code in gen_code(), also added $alpha = gen_code_alpha(); , And did all other solutions, And Again it didn't work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Variables defined inside functions exist only inside those functions. Instead of setting a global variable, you should `return` the value from your function:

```
function gen_license_key()
{
    return gen_code(4) . '-' .
        gen_code(4) . '-' .
        gen_code(4) . '-' .
        gen_code(4) . '-' .
        gen_code(2);
}
```

Then you can get a new value by assigning a variable to the value returned by your function:

```
$licenseKey = gen_license_key();
echo $licenseKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go down this path of properly using global variables, then you would have to reference them first, and early if you are assigning to them. Also, since it seems like you are not utilizing `$alpha` outside of those functions, just return those values and avoid that [global namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php) pollution.

You also have a typo where `$rand` isn't the name of a variable, but the function [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php), which has been corrected.

```
<?php
function gen_code_alpha()
{
    $alpha = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        $alpha .= $i;
    }

    // This attaches alphabets from 'a' to 'z' to our $alpha
    for ($i = 65; $i <= 122; $i++) {
        $alpha .= chr($i);
    }
    return $alpha;
}

function gen_code($len = 1)
{
    $alpha = gen_code_alpha();

    $strlen = strlen($alpha);

    $code = '';
    for ($k = 0; $k < $len; $k++) {
        $i = rand(0, $strlen -1);// now wanna randomly generate the code
        $code .= substr($alpha, $i, 1);
    }

    return $code;
}

function gen_license_key()
{
    global $licenseKey;
    $licenseKey = gen_code(4) . '-' .
                  gen_code(4) . '-' .
                  gen_code(4) . '-' .
                  gen_code(4) . '-' .
                  gen_code(2);
}

gen_license_key();
echo $licenseKey;
?>
```

[Try it Online! (Demo)](https://tio.run/##xVLLboMwELzzFXtAMijvqK1UAc0H9Np75JBNjEJsZIyitOq307VNyAMp1/qAl92dnZ2BSlRtm64qUQW7RuamUBL2KNe52uKal5XgURz8BEAndK@QAWNJ4DI7pSEKC0rNE6A7zeDdBqNRDB5zg5tmVElc9tfDZzP4EkUN3BieC6TANm7Q1LDT6giMMzAK2Le7VKO7UQ/cb68X8sVy@Yw@F5oQ8WUH@9RoGi27niSgxQYuRGGJkmgWAx8efepcCWujPcQHkQf0ZQvpXLwKOXQmHiAFS2jDBx1Wq@ZyG83HPcdkESdko1QnOHEpuWtQx/Jsl0PNDYIRCJbyOsgtQH7UzYbGdOvRzGJMIu@@0MUeixi6UxY5yhrXBzz3P8m@VBtekgRf@8SzH3iTuHEueolhCmzCYNqvdz3/2LWMndyByiTAXKh7eauPtv0D)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function gen_code_alpha()
{
    $alpha = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        $alpha .= $i;
    }

    // This attaches alphabets from 'a' to 'z' to our $alpha
    for ($i = 65; $i <= 122; $i++) {
        $alpha .= chr($i);
    }
}

function gen_code($len = 1)
{
    gen_code_alpha();
    global $alpha;

    $strlen = strlen($alpha);

    $code = '';
    for ($k = 0; $k < $len; $k++) {
        $i = rand(0, $strlen -1);// now wanna randomly generate the code
        $code .= substr($alpha, $i, 1);
    }

    return $code;
}

function gen_license_key()
{
    $licenseKey = gen_code(4) . '-' .
                    gen_code(4) . '-' .
                    gen_code(4) . '-' .
                    gen_code(4) . '-' .
                    gen_code(2);
return $licenseKey;
}

$licenseKey = gen_license_key();
echo $licenseKey;
?>
```

We need to return a variable in function and also `$rand` is not a variable `rand()` is a function.

Comment: Please explain the differences in your code. You provide a code-only answer, which is discouraging since it doesn't help others understand your thought process or reasoning on why this would be a good answer to the question.

Comment: Kindly check last line i explain the error also in comment

Comment: I did not scroll down to see the text initially, because I assumed everything in the code block was code. I fixed your answer to reflect this more accurately.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, i will try to improve myself to add the comments more understandable.